# SQL server IF begin statement in where function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement, where-clause

I'm trying to create the following in a where statement.

```
    where Registration_Date >=@StartDate and Registration_Date < dateadd(day,1,@EndDate) 
        and if @affiliateid is null begin Channel in (select Value from dbo.Split(',',@Channel)) end 
             else Affiliate_Id in (select Value from dbo.Split(',', @AffiliateId))
        and Registration_Channel in (select Value from dbo.Split(',', @Channel))
```

So, I am trying to say that if @AffiliateId is null, use the @Channel input for all Affiliate ids, if not then use the specific @AffiliateId, irrespective of channels.

Is there any way I could make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   DATE(registration_date) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
        AND EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    dbo.split(',', COALESCE(@affiliateId, @channel))
        WHERE   value = CASE WHEN @affiliateId IS NULL THEN channel ELSE affiliateId END
        )
        AND EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    dbo.split(',', @channel)
        WHERE   value = registration_channel
        )
```

In `SQL Server 2008`, `DATE(column)` is a sargable expression.